# How to use NOT IN clause in sqlalchemy ORM query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

how do i convert the following mysql query to sqlalchemy?

```
SELECT * FROM `table_a` ta, `table_b` tb where 1
AND ta.id = tb.id
AND ta.id not in (select id from `table_c`)
```

so far i have this for sqlalchemy:

```
query = session.query(table_a, table_b)
query = query.filter(table_a.id == table_b.id)
```

Comment: I had some weird issue using `in_(1,2,3)`.. I got: 'ColumnOperators.in_() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given', so I changed to `between(1,3)` instead and it worked.. In my scenario I had two `in_` clauses within an `and_` clause too  - not sure if that combo causes odd message in SQLAlchemy 1.4.41.

Answer (score 122):

The ORM internals describe the [**`not_in()`**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.PropComparator.not_in) operator (previously `notin_()`), so you can say:

```
query = query.filter(table_a.id.not_in(subquery))
#                               ^^^^^^
```

From the docs:

> *inherited from the [`ColumnOperators.not_in()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.not_in) method of [ColumnOperators](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators)*
>
> implement the NOT IN operator.
>
> This is equivalent to using negation with [ColumnOperators.in_()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_), i.e. ~x.in_(y).

Note that [version 1.4 states](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.PropComparator.not_in):

> The `not_in()` operator is renamed from `notin_()` in previous releases. The previous name remains available for backwards compatibility.

So you may find `notin_()` in some cases.

Comment: This also works with a simple list in place of subquery. I.e. `notin_([42, 43, 44, 45])`

Comment: Renamed to `not_in()` in 1.4. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.not_in

Comment: Version 1.3.6 ```notin_()``` works!!

Answer (score 80):

Try this:

```
subquery = session.query(table_c.id)
query = query.filter(~table_a.id.in_(subquery))
```

Note: `table_a`, `table_b` and `table_c` should be mapped classes, not `Table` instances.

Comment: hello. how do i join table_a and table_b in this example?

Comment: I assume, that `query` is query object that you showed above.

Comment: ohh ok now i get it. initially i was lost because i thought the example was not for join table.

Comment: this also works `query = query.filter(table_a.id.notin_(subquery))`

Comment: What if the element is `None` ?

Answer (score 19):

here is the full code:

```
#join table_a and table_b
query = session.query(table_a, table_b)
query = query.filter(table_a.id == table_b.id)

# create subquery
subquery = session.query(table_c.id)
# select all from table_a not in subquery
query = query.filter(~table_a.id.in_(subquery))
```